# A phrase for exhibiting something

Tags: phrase-request

I wrote:

> The selected sentences are listed **for the view of the user**.

I mean the software lists the sentences so that the user can view and check them, but my sentence is not valid or common, what are ways to say such a phrase?

It also can be about a gallery, "the pictures are there for the view of people"?

Comment: "listed for the user to view" should work

Comment: I'd probably say, "The selected sentences are presented to the user".

Comment: It sort of goes without saying that the user can view things that are in front of their eyeballs. If the idea is for the user to check them, maybe something like: "The selected sentences are listed for the user to review."

Answer (score 1):

For the example you have given, a correct wording would be:

> The selected sentences are listed **for the user to review**.

However, the alternate example has a different answer:

> The pictures are there for the **people to view**.